# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation

Tags: java, xml-parsing, compiler-errors, apache-poi

So I know a similar question has been asked in regards to this error. I know it's because there's something wrong with the code which is why it's not compiling. My problem is that I don't know where exactly in my code the error is and I can't figure it out. Just to sum up the program, it's an XML parser that creates a TreeNode data structure and exports it into excel. Before I added the feature of it exporting to excel, it was working perfectly fine. But when I used apache poi to export it to excel for some reason there's been compilation problems, but I can't see how that might be where the error is being caused. Can anyone spot what/where in the code this problem is occuring? Cheers

Edit:- apologies! This is the error:-
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
at HMDB.XML.main(XML.java:200)

It's strange because the line of coding it seems to occur at is a blank line. It appears to be occurring in the subElements method, directly below this bit of code :-

```
    '} else if (event == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS
            && !reader.isWhiteSpace()) {

        newNode.getElement().setValue(reader.getText())'
```

This is the code:-

package HMDB;

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
public class XML {

private int rowNum = 0;
private int columnNum = 0;

public XMLStreamReader xmlInput() {

    XMLStreamReader reader = null;

    try {

        XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        InputStream file = new FileInputStream(
                "Users/kevlar/Dropbox/PhD/Java/Metabolites/src/HMDB/HMDB00316.xml");
        reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(file);

    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        System.err.println("XMLStreamException : " + e.getMessage());

    } catch (FactoryConfigurationError e) {
        System.err.println("FactoryConfigurationError : " + e.getMessage());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("FileNotFoundException : " + e.getMessage());

    }
    return reader;
}

private void findElements(String input) throws XMLStreamException {

    TreeNode[] children;
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Metabolites");
    String[] elementsSplit = input.split("\\s*,\\s*");
    xmlInput();
    XMLStreamReader reader = xmlInput();
    reader.nextTag();

    do {
        if (reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT
                && reader.getLocalName() == "metabolite") {
            children = mainElements(reader).children();

            printValues(children, elementsSplit, sheet1);
            children = null;
        } else {
            reader.next();
        }
    } while (reader.hasNext());

    reader.close();

    try {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("HMDB.xls");
        wb.write(output);
        output.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void printValues(TreeNode[] children, String[] elementsSplit,
        Sheet sheet1) {

    rowNum++;
    Row row = sheet1.createRow(rowNum);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(columnNum);

    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        TreeNode element = children[i];
        String elementName = element.getElementName();

        for (int j = 0; j < elementsSplit.length; j++) {
            String searchName = elementsSplit[j];

            if (searchName.equals(elementName)) {

                if (element.hasChildren()) {
                    recurse(element.children(), cell);
                } else {
                    columnNum++;
                    cell.setCellValue(element.getElementValue());
                    System.out.println("Element:- "
                            + element.getElementName() + " | Value:- "
                            + element.getElementValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cell = null;
}

private void recurse(TreeNode[] children, Cell cell) {

    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        TreeNode node = children[i];
        if (node.hasChildren()) {
            System.out.println("Element:- " + node.getElementName()
                    + " and it's subelements:- ");
            recurse(node.children(), cell);
        }

        else if (!node.hasChildren()) {
            columnNum++;
            cell.setCellValue(node.getElementValue());
            System.out.println("Element:- " + node.getElementName()
                    + " | Value:- " + node.getElementValue());
        }
    }
}

private TreeNode mainElements(XMLStreamReader reader)
        throws XMLStreamException {

    Element rootElement = new Element();
    rootElement.setName(reader.getLocalName());
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(rootElement);

    int level = 1;

    do {
        int event = reader.next();

        if (event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {

            Element element = new Element();
            element.setName(reader.getLocalName());
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(element);
            level++;

            if (level == 2) {
                root.add(subElements(reader, node));
                level--;

            }

        } else if (event == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT) {
            level--;
        }

    } while (level > 0);

    return root;
}

private TreeNode subElements(XMLStreamReader reader, TreeNode node)
        throws XMLStreamException {

    int level = 1;

    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
    newNode = node;

    do {
        int event = reader.next();

        if (event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {

            Element subElement = new Element();
            subElement.setName(reader.getLocalName());
            TreeNode subNode = new TreeNode(subElement);
            level++;

            if (level == 2) {
                newNode.add(subElements(reader, subNode));
                level--;
            }

        } else if (event == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS
                && !reader.isWhiteSpace()) {

            newNode.getElement().setValue(reader.getText());

        } else if (event == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT) {
            level--;
        }

    } while (level > 0);

    return newNode;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException {

    XML test = new XML();
    test.findElements("accession, inchikey");

}

}

package HMDB;

public class Element {

private String name;
private String value;

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public void setValue(String value){
    this.value = value;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getValue(){
    return value;
}

}


package HMDB;

public class TreeNode{


/**
 * This is the nodes parent node. If it is the root of the tree, 
 * then it will be null
 */
private TreeNode parent;

/**
 * An array of all this nodes children nodes. If it's a leaf node 
 * i.e. node with no children, then length will be zero
 */
private TreeNode[] children = new TreeNode[0];

private Element element;

public TreeNode()
{

}

/**
 * Assigns the element object of this tree node to the one passed
 * through
 * @param element
 */
public TreeNode(Element element){
    this.element = element;
}

public void setElement(Element element){
    this.element = element;
}

public Element getElement(){
    return element;
}

public String getElementName(){
    return element.getName();
}

public String getElementValue(){
    return element.getValue();
}



 /**
   * Adds the <code>child</code> node to this container making this its parent.
   * 
   * @param child is the node to add to the tree as a child of <code>this</code>
   * 
   * @param index is the position within the children list to add the
   *  child.  It must be between 0 (the first child) and the
   *  total number of current children (the last child).  If it is
   *  negative the child will become the last child.
   */
  public void add (TreeNode child, int index)
  {
    // Add the child to the list of children.
    if ( index < 0 || index == children.length )  // then append
    {
      TreeNode[] newChildren = new TreeNode[ children.length + 1 ];
      System.arraycopy( children, 0, newChildren, 0, children.length );
      newChildren[children.length] = child;
      children = newChildren;
    }
    else if ( index > children.length )
    {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot add child to index " + index + ".  There are only " + children.length + " children.");
    }
    else  // insert
    {
      TreeNode[] newChildren = new TreeNode[ children.length + 1 ];
      if ( index > 0 )
      {
        System.arraycopy( children, 0, newChildren, 0, index );
      }
      newChildren[index] = child;
      System.arraycopy( children, index, newChildren, index + 1, children.length - index );
      children = newChildren;
    }

    // Set the parent of the child.
    child.parent = this;
  }

  /**
   * Adds the <code>child</code> node to this container making this its parent.
   * The child is appended to the list of children as the last child.
   */
  public void add (TreeNode child)
  {
    add( child, -1 );
  }

  /**
   * Gets a list of all the child nodes of this node.
   * 
   * @return An array of all the child nodes.  The array will
   *  be the size of the number of children.  A leaf node
   *  will return an empty array, not <code>null</code>.
   */
  public TreeNode[] children ()
  {
    return children;
  }

  /**
   * Returns if this node has children or if it is a leaf
   * node.
   * 
   * @return <code>true</code> if this node has children; <code>false</code>
   *  if it does not have any children.
   */
  public boolean hasChildren ()
  {
    if ( children.length == 0 )
    {
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Gets the position of this node in the list of siblings
   * managed by the parent node.  This node can be obtained
   * by <code>this = parent.children[this.index()]</code>.
   * 
   * @return The index of the child array of this node's
   *  parent.  If this is the root node it will return -1.
   */
  public int index ()
  {
    if ( parent != null )
    {
      for ( int i = 0; ; i++ )
      {
        Object node = parent.children[i];

        if ( this == node )
        {
          return i;
        }
      }
    }

    // Only ever make it here if this is the root node.
    return -1;
  }

}
```

Comment: You should always post the error...

Comment: Full stack trace, if possible, and mark the line when it happens in your code. If it is really a compilation error, not an exception thrown while running the program, then copy the wording of the error exactly (and still mark the line in the code where it happens).

Comment: Just updated the question specifying where it's occurring with the error message sorry!

Comment: Show your `import` statements also. Copy-paste the whole class file.

Comment: Just added them now!

Comment: @user2062207 I've posted an answer given the code you've posted here. I assume nothing is missing.

Answer (score 1):

These are not all the imports. You are missing imports for TreeNode and Element objects. You need to import these classes to use them in your file. These are the only compilation errors based on the code you've posted.

Comment: Just added them in now!

Comment: I've edited the code section in the post above with the TreeNode and Element classes below the XML one. The TreeNode and Element class are all part of the same package so I just instantiate the classes to make objects of them.